# On Ext-duals of injective modules for commutative rings

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring and $I=E(R/p)$ the injective hull of the module $R/p$ for a prime ideal $p$.

> Question: Is there a (more) explicit description of the $R$-modules $Ext_R^i(I,R)$ for $i \geq 0$ (at least in special cases such as $R$ being Gorenstein)? When are those modules finitely generated?